# When to use split and str.split() on a pandas Series?

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I want to know that why we can't use split instead of str.split in the below code and while creating "ID" variable why two times ".str" has been used

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)
for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:2]=='02':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:2]=='03':
    df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
if col[:1]=='№':
    df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)

names_ids = df.index.str.split('\s\(') 
df.index = names_ids.str[0] # the [0] element is the country name (new index) 
df['ID'] = names_ids.str[1].str[:3] # the [1] element is the abbreviation or 
                       #ID (take first 3 characters from that)
```

.str converts to string,what's the purpose to use it in creating "ID" variable? 
  .And what's the difference between split and 
   str.split?

Comment: `split` is a method. Index objects and `pd.Series` objects have no method called `split`. `str`ing objects, on the other hand, do have a method called `split`. You could also create your own class with a method called `split`. Here you have to use `.str.split` because `.str` gives you access to an inner class called `StringMethods` which happen to have a `split` method

Comment: Also notice that `.str` *does NOT* convert anything to string. I would really suggest you take a look at the Docs first

Comment: You really should [read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) before asking such questions.

Comment: I read that but couldn't understand properly that's why I asked over here.

Comment: It would help understand the code's intent if you post a few lines of `'olympics.csv'`, currently it's not reproducible. You can answer your own question by inspecting `type(names_ids)`, `type(names_ids.str)` etc. or doing `dir()` on them to see which ones support (vectorized) string methods and which ones don't.